# Access a Derby database from JSP

Tags: jsp, tomcat, derby

My question is in the title. I am new to Java web development and I am currently working on an assignment that requires the use of only JSP, Derby and Tomcat (servlet, scripting languages, beans and frameworks are banned). I have created a Derby database which is located in D:\Software\Apache\derby\db-derby-10.10.1.1-bin\lib\databases, and the content of my JSP file is as follows:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Testing Java: <% out.print("Welcome to Ninja Loot"); %>!</p>

        <sql:setDataSource url="jdbc:derby:D:\Software\Apache\derby\db-derby-10.10.1.1-bin\lib\databases\mydb" var="mydb" driver="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
        <sql:query dataSource="${mydb}" var="result">
            SELECT * FROM PEOPLE;
        </sql:query>
        <table border="1" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <th>Forename</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${row.Forename}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${row.Surname}"/></td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

however, the following line throws an exception saying "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /test.jsp at line 14" and I cannot figure out why.

```
<sql:setDataSource url="jdbc:derby:D:\Software\Apache\derby\db-derby-10.10.1.1-bin\lib\databases\mydb" var="mydb" driver="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
```

Stacktrace: 
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrappe‌​r.java:568) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)

Could someone please point out what is wrong in my code? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The Tomcat log (catalina.out) should have some more detailed information.

Comment: You should ban your teacher. Accessing databases from JSPs is against all best practices. Servlets (calling other classes written in Java) should be used to do that. The `sql` tag library is officially documented as something that shouldn't be used except for serious code.

Comment: That said, post the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @JBNizet here is the full stack trace: Stacktrace:
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: @BeauGrantham I could not find "catalina.out", but found "catalina.2014-03-30.log" instead. The content is too long to be pasted here though...

Comment: Try changing your backslashes to forward slashes in your data source URL. Or, try doubling them from '\' to '\\'. Also, make sure that derby.jar is packaged in your war file in the library area.

Comment: @BryanPendleton thank you for your tips. I changed \ to \\ and the problem has been resolved, but now the sql:query tag gives me an error.
Stacktrace:
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)